# How can i write Simple Mbean to monitor JBOSS server

Tags: java, jboss, jmx

I would like to monitor the **JVM** of the **JBOSS Server.**

I have seen the **JCONSOLE** but How can i develop my own Mbean to Monitor the Server.

Is there any easy ways,kindly redirect me to learn about JMX  or else give me a simple tutorial.

Comment: What are you looking to monitor that isn't already monitored through the JMX console and existing beans?

Comment: Im trying to write a code for monitoring the JVM of the JBOSS app server.. Im trying to start up , give me any suggestions to achieve it easily

Answer (score 0):

You find a small tutorial and sample code to develop a MBean here: http://middlewaremagic.com/jboss/?p=2152